# Using a Grid Element in a Sub-Table cell causes a page break to be added to PDF export

Tags: birt

Currently, my report is set up with a Child table placed in a row of a Parent table.  Each row of the child table has a Grid element that allows me to have more control over the format of the report.  There are several fields in the child report with varying field lengths so a Field per Column of the report won't work.  Note that I am only setting the data source of the Tables, not of the grid elements.

This works when rendering to HTML, however, when rendering to a PDF file a page break appears just before the row containing the child page.

Things I have tried to resolve the issue with:

- Setting page breaks to "Avoid"
- Setting the page break interval to something high
- Tested with 2.6.2 and 3.7.2.  4.2 currently will not run on my machine.

When you using a column for each field in the table instead of a Grid element in a single cell, the problem goes away but this is undesirable as there are multiple fields with varying field lengths.  Merging multiple cells to make room for the different lengths does work, but it can become unruly when you need to change the report format.

The size of the grid/table does not matter - this happens even when I am only using a couple fields from the data set.

After some more experimentation, I found out that if I remove all Detail Rows of the Parent table that are before the Child Table row, the report is created properly.  Unfortunately I need to have rows of information ahead of the Child Table so this does not solve the issue.

Does anyone have a solution?